# CLion multi-project setup

Tags: clion

Installed CLion and playing with 1.1.

So I want total setup to resemble somewhat Visual Studio - so I could add few library projects, at least two executable (cmd-line and UI) plus tests. Cannot figure out how to add, say, library projects (and mark them as shared libraries), and them add library include dir to both execs and test.

Comment: Did you find any solutions ??

Comment: @Shiro yes, do you need an example?

Comment: I would love an example. I am trying to do the same, but the only way I found is to just make new projects on new windows

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Could you please provide example if you found one? I think you can make it as an answer to this question. Thanks a lot.